# OnActivityResult not called if not requesting permissions

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-lifecycle

My app is starting an activity from another package with `startActivityForResult`. I observed problems when my launching activity gets recreated and saw that `onActivityResult` is not called in that case after the started activity returns. (It is called correctly if I do not trigger activity recreation.)

These are the steps I performed:

- Start my activity
- Click my button which calls `startActivityForResult` on the ykDroid app
- Bring my app to background. This causes my activity to be destroyed as I have enabled this in the Android developer settings
- Bring my app back to foreground (I see OnCreate is called)
- Swipe a Yubikey NEO which causes the other activity to return.
- Watch logcat to see that OnActivityResult is not called.

I found out that if I call `RequestPermissions` for Permission.UseFingerprint I get the OnActivityResult callback even after activity recreation. I don't have a clue why. Can anybody explain this behavior?
Could it be related to ykDroid? see https://github.com/pp3345/ykDroid for their source code.

Here is what I used for testing (Xamarin Android):

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/MyTheme")]
public class DatabaseSettingsActivity : Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.yubichall_test);

        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_yubichall).Click += (sender, args) =>
        {

            byte[] challenge64 = new byte[64];
            for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            {
                challenge64[i] = (byte) i;


            }
            var chalIntent = TryGetYubichallengeIntentOrPrompt(challenge64, true);

            StartActivityForResult(chalIntent, 123);

        };


        //Uncomment this and it will work
        /* if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 23)
            RequestPermissions(new[] { Manifest.Permission.UseFingerprint }, 99);*/
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Kp2aLog.Log("OnActivityResult: " + requestCode);
        if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            byte[] challengeResponse = data.GetByteArrayExtra("response");
            if ((challengeResponse != null) && (challengeResponse.Length > 0))
            {
                FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text_result).Text =
                    MemUtil.ByteArrayToHexString(challengeResponse);

            }
        }
    }


    public Intent TryGetYubichallengeIntentOrPrompt(byte[] challenge, bool promptToInstall)
    {
        Intent chalIntent = new Intent("net.pp3345.ykdroid.intent.action.CHALLENGE_RESPONSE");
        chalIntent.PutExtra("challenge", challenge);

        IList<ResolveInfo> activities = PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(chalIntent, 0);
        bool isIntentSafe = activities.Count > 0;
        if (isIntentSafe)
        {
            return chalIntent;
        }
        if (promptToInstall)
        {
            //please install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.pp3345.ykdroid&hl=en
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

where the layout yubicall_test is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <Button android:id="@+id/btn_yubichall"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="yubi challenge"
  />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If that fixes your issue than why not request permission anyway you have to have runtime permissions in your app!

Comment: because 1.) not everybody has API Level >= 23 2.) it doesn't make sense to request fingerprint permissions if I don't need them 3.) I don't think this will actually solve the problem on all devices 4.) I don't like fixes I do not understand.